# El uso de "que + no" o "que + sí" durante unas circunstancias emocionantes al responder a alguien

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras

En varias películas ví el idiomático uso siguiente de "que + no" o "que + sí" en diálogos.

De "Hogar" España (en una situación en la que una mujer no podía creer de lo que acababa de saber sobre su novio):

*-Me dijo que......necesitaba ayuda, que se le había ido de las manos.*

*-No. No.*

*-Lara....*

*-¡****Que** no**!*

De "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España):

*-¡Que salgas de aquí!*

*-¡****Que** no**!*

Un ejemplo más de "La Víctima Número Ocho":

*-Yo seguro que voy a tener que ir a que me den puntos.*

*-**Que no**, hombre, **que no**...*

De "Contratiempo" España (aquí una mujer disculpa por haber respondido tan emocionante a su novio):

*-¡Que no vengas, por favor!*

*-Laura, ¿estás bien?*

*-Perdona, **que no**, **que no**. **Que no** pasa nada, de verdad, estoy bien.*

Un ejemplo más de "Contratiempo":

*-¿Y si ha conocido a otra chica?*

*-**Que no**, Tomás, **que no**. Todo esto es muy raro.*

De "El Desconocido" España (cuando un hombre no dejó a otro hombre aparcar un coche):

*-Haces el favor de mover el coche?*

*-¿**Que sí**, que ya lo muevo!*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo usar esta estructura? ¿En cuáles circunstancias?
2. ¿Sería gramaticalmente incorrecto no usar "que" en estos ejemplos? ¿O "que" es imprescindible aquí?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores si hay algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuando con la explicación vertida en [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35279/el-uso-de-que-en-circunstancias-espec%C3%ADficas), veamos el valor de "que" en los casos que faltan:

- ¡Que salgas de aquí! / -¡**Que** no!
- Yo seguro que voy a tener que ir a que me den puntos. / - **Que** no, hombre, **que** no...
- ¡**Que** no vengas, por favor!
- Perdona, **que** no, **que** no. **Que** no pasa nada, de verdad, estoy bien.
- **Que** no, Tomás, **que** no.
- ¡**Que** sí, **que** ya lo muevo!

En el segundo caso, "que" tiene un valor exhortativo.

En todos los demás casos, se trataría de una conjunción de valor vacío que refuerza la afirmación o la negación. También podría considerarse como una conjunción subordinante nominal donde la proposición principal se ha elidido:

- (Te digo / Te repito) **Que** sí / **Que** no.